# Spamassassin ignores spam in multi-part email

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis

Sometimes my email server gets multi-part emails where the embedded email is detected as spam, but the containing email gets a score of 0. So the message is marked as ***SPAM*** but not moved to the quarantine folder, still delivered to the recipient. What can I do to change this?

This is on a Debian/Postfix/Dovecot/Spamassassin/Amavis system.

Comment: Going to need more details. [Start with providing](https://serverfault.com/posts/1117294/edit) sample headers (including those added by SpamAssassin), relevant configuration & logs and the specific commands you ran to confirm that the message is "detected" but still awarded a "scored of 0".

Comment: Are you aware that a fairly common way of configuring SpamAssassin is to set a positive threshold, only scored above which are eligible for direct action? There may not be anything wrong with a zero-scoring message not receiving special treatment, maybe there simply were not sufficiently strong spam signals detected?

Answer (score 0):

Attachments are not included in the body of an email and are not scanned by SpamAssassin. To overcome this, using "raw" rule or plugin or combine with software such as ClamAV antivirus can extract parts of the attachment, but writing a signature to detect it is necessary.